# How to automate subsetting multiple files using r

Tags: r, csv, subset

Hi guys am new to R and I am comfortable with creating subsets if i handle one file at a time .... But I am having trouble automating that to multiple files...So in my case,I want to automate the process of subsetting multiple csv files which are present in multiple subfolders of a given folder ...I want to create multiple subset files which include say the the 100 rows of each file and write them into new files and the name of the subsetted files should be same as that of the file from which they were subsetted... Any help appreciated... Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

I created a couple of `subfolders` in my folder `Temp`.  If the working directory is `Temp`.  Assuming that the number of rows in each dataset is `>= 100`

```
files <- list.files(recursive=TRUE, full.names=TRUE)
files
#[1] "./Temp1/file1.csv"   "./Temp2/file2_2.csv" "./Temp2/file2.csv" 

lst1 <- lapply(files, function(x) read.csv(x, sep='')[1:100,])
Pref <- sub("/[^/]+$", '', files)
```

The `subset` files are then written to the corresponding folders along with the `old` file.

```
invisible(lapply(seq_along(lst1), function(i) 
            write.csv(lst1[[i]],paste(Pref[i],paste0('Subset',
           basename(files[i])), sep="/"), quote=FALSE, row.names=FALSE)))

list.files(recursive=TRUE, full.names=TRUE)
#[1] "./Temp1/file1.csv"         "./Temp1/Subsetfile1.csv"  
#[3] "./Temp2/file2_2.csv"       "./Temp2/file2.csv"        
#[5] "./Temp2/Subsetfile2_2.csv" "./Temp2/Subsetfile2.csv"
```

Comment: can u explain me what "sub("/[^/]+$", '', files)" means. I read the documentation but i could't understand y used that particular pattern "/[^/]+$"

Comment: I am getting the following error wen i ran the above code :       "Error in read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  : more columns than column names  " ... Can someone explain on how to tackle with this error ... Any help great;y appreciated ... Thanks!!!

Comment: @SarathChandra Regarding the first comment,1) I was replacing the `/file\\d+.csv` with `''` ie. extracting the first part `./Temp`, 2) You can change the `sep=','` for your dataset.  In the files I created, the `sep=''` works. 3) It is easier for others if you show at least a few lines in your post.  The `Error` message is quite obvious that there are more columns in your dataset.  You could use `skip=1` and `header=FALSE` in `read.csv` and later change the column names.