# How to select the same columns from many files

Tags: r

I have many text files in which I want to load them all and then make a new matrix with a certain columns from all files

for example some matrices are as follows:

```
1a <- replicate(10, rnorm(20)) 
1b <- replicate(10, rnorm(19)) 
2a <- replicate(10, rnorm(18))
2b <- replicate(10, rnorm(15))
```

how I reconize them, I put them all in a folder and I set my directory there 
then I can get the list of them like

```
filelist = list.files(pattern = ".*.txt")
```

Then I want to put the first column of the 1a and V6 and V7 in a new matrix
then I want to put the V6 and V7 from the 1b in a new matrix
then I want to put the V6 and V7 from the 2a  in a new matrix 
then I want to put the V6 and V7 from the 2b in a new matrix

The files are not in the same length (their rows are different from each other) . I would like to do two things

1- save the same file with selected columns with an added R to the name 
for example if the original file is 1a, then select V6 and V7 and same a new file with only 2 columns and name 1aR

2- make a new matrix and put all the selected columns in that (those that are not equal , we can make NA or 0 there

Comment: see `write.table` or `write.csv`

Comment: @Heroka did you read my question fully? is it the same as that question???????? I am sorry but the title is similar

Comment: In my opinion, at least the first part of your question is answered by the duplicate. For the second part, you might need to do manual subsetting/column selecting as you need a different column from each.

Comment: @Heroka you reply when I need to pick up the same columns from all. if you reply that I will accept. if you dont know, please don't just down vote a question. There are many people out there who are expert in R. you cannot just down vote a question, if you cannot reply !!!

Comment: @Heroka I changed my question , the first part I removed and now I did it the way you said you can do.

Comment: Given the new question (load 100 files, subset the 6th and 7th column for each), look into how for-loops or how apply functions work. Here is a slightly more complicated version of your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27437144/how-to-automate-subsetting-multiple-files-using-r

Comment: You may try `filelist <- list.files(pattern='\\d+[^0-9]+\\.txt', full.names=TRUE); lst <- lapply(filelist, read.csv, header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE); cbind(lst[[1]][1], do.call(cbind, lapply(lst, `[`, 6:7)))`

Comment: @akrun  thanks do you load the txt file with read.csv? or fread or read.table? however, I would like to know what if the length of the rows where not equal ? Please check the question again. because I want the question to be different that people dont down vote it :-(

Comment: @koskeshkiramtodahanet You can use either one of the options to load the data.  With `fread`, it would be fast though.  If the lengths of the rows are not equal, the `cbind` option will not work.  Then, we may need to populate with `NA` rows so that the nrow will be equal for all.

Comment: @akrun NA or 0 would be fine

Comment: @koskeshkiramtodahanet  I posted a solution below.  Hope it helps you.

Comment: Just a doubt, do you want to `cbind` the selected columns only in the `1a` and `1b` together, likewise, only `2a` and `2b` together?  In that case, there will be 2 output dataset.

Comment: @akrun no all together but in the right way. 1a then 1b then 2a then 2b and also I want to save each file separated saved too

Comment: @koskeshkiramtodahanet  Can you check the solution below.  If I understand, you want a single file that contains the 6th and 7th column from all the dataset and then save it as a separate file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an option to read the files, select the concerned columns from the dataset, and create a new dataset.

We get the files that follow a particular file name pattern in the working directory using `list.files`.

```
filelist <- list.files(pattern='\\d+[^0-9]+\\.txt', full.names=TRUE)
```

Then, read all the files into a `list` using either `read.csv/read.table` or `fread` from `data.table`

```
lst <- lapply(filelist, read.csv, header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Extract the 6th and 7th columns from the 'lst'

```
lst1 <- lapply(lst, "[", c("V6", "V7"))
```

If the `data.frame` elements in the `list` have unequal number of rows, one option is `cbind.fill` from `library(rowr)`

```
library(rowr)
res <- cbind.fill(lst[[1]][1], do.call(cbind.fill, 
           c(lst1, list(fill=NA))), fill=NA)
res 
#   V1 V6 V7 V6.1 V7.1
#1  21  1 11    1   11
#2  22  2 12    2   12
#3  23  3 13    3   13
#4  24  4 14   NA   NA
#5  25  5 15   NA   NA
#6  26  6 16   NA   NA
#7  27  7 17   NA   NA
#8  28  8 18   NA   NA
#9  29  9 19   NA   NA
#10 30 10 20   NA   NA
```

Then, we write the file as `.txt`

```
write.table(res, 'CombinedV6_V7.txt', row.names=FALSE, quote=FALSE)
```

#### Update

Using the data from the link

```
lst <- lapply(filelist, read.csv, sep='\t',
              header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
lst1 <- lapply(lst, "[", c("Time", "X220"))
res <- do.call(cbind.fill, c(lst1, list(fill=NA)))
head(res)
#   Time   X220  Time   X220  Time  X220   Time  X220
#1 0.700    111 1.400   2370 0.850   520  1.600 21216
#2 2.083 131747 1.650 179289 1.633 54607  1.900  3816
#3 2.517  23428 2.100  21690 2.117 13677  2.117  3573
#4 2.667  12528 2.267  10383 2.267 13448  2.300 11349
#5 3.883   1055 3.017    816 3.567  1346  9.717   292
#6 4.500    881 3.383    637 5.350   772 21.600  3774
```

#### data

```
 lst <- list(data.frame(V1=21:30, V6=1:10, V7= 11:20), 
             data.frame(V6=1:3, V7=11:13, V1= 21:23))
```

NOTE: The above data is just for reproducing the problem.

Comment: @koskeshkiramtodahanet  Can you check the `str(lst)`?  I have to use `sep="\t"` as the delimiter.  It is working for me after that change.  Please check the updated solution

Comment: I have only few questions to learn. what is the differences if I use ".*.txt   or   \\d+[^0-9]+\\.txt ? what if I set recursive=TRUE there (based on previous comments you put. what the last function does ? lst <- list

Comment: @koskeshkiramtodahanet  I used the `\\d+[^0-9]+` to make it a bit more specific as it seems like your file names start with one or more numbers followed by one or more characters followed by `.txt`.  The last one `lst <- list(..` was just to create a reproducible data in case anybody wants to test it.

Comment: thank you so much for the explanation and your amazing help. I accepted it. However, I would like to know something (first part of my question) I read the files in a listfiles and I select two columns from each file. is it possible to save them as a new file automatically ? in the same folder ? or I must do it manually

Comment: @koskeshkiramtodahanet  We can save them as a new file, For example, TRy `nm1 <- paste0('new', basename(filelist));
invisible(lapply(seq_along(lst1), function(i) write.table(lst1[[i]], nm1[i], row.names=FALSE, quote=FALSE)))`

Comment: this will create 4 files with only those selected columns in them?

Comment: @koskeshkiramtodahanet Yes, it should create 4 files with that selected columns as the `lst1` is a list of data.frames with that columns.  If the working directory is different than the the one where you loaded the files, then you may need to specify the `path` with `paste` to save it in that directory.